# Expanding Cluster Drive space

Tags: sql-server, clustering, disk-space, system-databases, master-system-database

I will need to expand my existing cluster drive (sql cluster with 2 node active and passive) which has sys and user database data files. My san admin told he will need to delete all the existing data and expand the size which is above 2 tb. I can detach all the system databases and user databases, move it to a temp storage and copy back once the space is added. or I can remove everything and restore all the system and user database from a full back up.
Just wanted an opinion about which process is the safest and wont break the cluster

Comment: Neither of these, create a new disk and add it to the cluster. Don't have single behemoth disks with single file behemoth databases on them outside of performance, it's an administrative nightmare.

Comment: I have separate drive for data and log file . I just want to expand the sizes of the disks.    So do you suggest to create additional disks and add secondary files for both data and log files that points towards the new disks?

Comment: Your disk is already "above 2 Terabytes" so yes, I'd create new disks and slowly move database files over. If you have a downtime you can do this during that time to more appropriately balance out the disk usage.

Comment: My disk is around 1 tb but i want it to be 2 tb .

Comment: I wouldn't even want it to be 1 tb - I'm not arguing with you, I'm just stating that if it were **me** having to take care of the system - I wouldn't go above 500 GB per disk for administrative and performance reasons. So asking if the process laid out seems "good" or not, I'm going with "not" and explained my rationale. It's just advice.

Comment: Im reluctant about moving the system files. I was thinking about creating an additional drive and when my cluster data disk  gets near full i will create a secondary data file and point towards the new drive